# struct vs vector as data holder

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a private function that will be used for some kind of interpolation (doesn't really matters).

I need to pass all the coefficients to it. the signature is as follow:

```
double Interpolation::evaluate(double t, double a1, double b1, double c1, double d1, double a2, double b2, double c2, double d2);
```

So thats may arguments. 
Now, I could store all these args in a different way for better readabiility. I was thinking about a struct

```
struct Coeffs
{
    double a1;
    double b1;
    double c1;
    double d1;
    double a2;
    double b2;
    double c2;
    double d2;
}

double Interpolation::evaluate(double t, Coeffs c);
```

or with a vector

```
double double Interpolation::evaluate(double t, std::vector<double> coeffs);
```

This function will potentially be called millions of time so I would like to keep it efficient. I suppose that having to instantiate a struct each time we want to call it is less efficient (according to what I read, struct is just a special kind of class), but I couldn't find any doc to confirm this.

Could someone with good c++ understanding advise me on the efficiency of instantiating structs vs vectors ( vs passing more than 8 args to a function)

Thanks

Comment: pass by reference anyway

Comment: yeah, pass by reference,
double Interpolation::evaluate(double t, Coeffs &c);
and if called million of times, consider making the function inline

Comment: Is the number of these coefficients constant?

Comment: Coeffs seems like a good idea. A vector will introduce all sorts of runtime error that will not happen with the struct.

Comment: You could pass an `std::array` with a fixed length

Comment: *Generally* you should use structures (or classes) for data that are closely related, and belongs to a single entity. And a vector (or array) for a collection of unrelated values of the same type. Start from that angle, and look for optimizations *after* you measure the code and figure out what (and where) the bottlenecks really are. Don't fall into the trap of premature optimization.

Comment: If a container (`std::vector` or `std::array`) is constructed and destructed millions of time, would it be a good idea to have a custom `std::allocator`? I would be interested in this.

Comment: Hi all, yes, the coeffs will be the same for consecutive calls, so I can pass by reference (seems obvious now that you say it) - Thanks!

Comment: @dani I don't have any answer other than "probably", but do note that `std::array` does not need an allocator since it has no dynamic storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct seems like a good idea. It lowers the burden of passing each elements to the function.

I would not advise to pass an `std::vector` as it introduce dynamic memory, and you don't need a dynamic number of parameter.

Alternatively, you could pass an `std::array` around I'd you which it have an array.

```
double interpolate(double t, std::array<double, 8>&& coeffs);
```

That way you don't even need to copy elements as it takes a temporary variable as a parameter.

Both the array and the struct version can be called like that:

```
interpolate (4.5, {
    1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1
});
```